# Ninject Array Bind

Tags: wpf, inversion-of-control, ninject

I'm trying to use Ninject with WPF

I have same interface for all my views

```
interface IView
{
  string ViewName { get; }
  object Content{ get; private set; } 
}

public partial class FirstView : IView
{
    ......
}
public partial class SecundView : IView
{
  ......
}
```

etc..

At start of App I Bind them using

```
Kernel.Bind<IView>().To<FirstView>();
Kernel.Bind<IView>().To<SecundView>();
........
........
```

I'm interested is there a way to register them by convention?
Something like:

```
.Kernel.Bind(
            x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                  .SelectAllClasses().InNamespaceOf<FirstView>()
                  .BindToInterface<IView>);
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Comment: .BindToInterface<> does not exist :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BindDefaultInterfaces()` method, which will bind every class which has the `View` word in their names to your `IView` interface:

```
.Kernel.Bind(
    x => x.FromThisAssembly()
          .SelectAllClasses().InNamespaceOf<FirstView>()
          .BindDefaultInterfaces());
```

You can also check the available "BindSomething" options [in the documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Projecting-Services-to-Bind).